# Powershell Reading XML file

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm attempting to read to following XML config file:

```
<configuration>
<userSettings>
    <setting name="FavoritesFolders">
        <value>
            <FavoritesFolder>
                <Subfolders>
                    <FolderName>ROOT</FolderName>
                </Subfolders>
            </FavoritesFolder>
        </value>
    </setting>
    <setting name="DefaultConnection">
        <value>
            <RDPConnectionProperties>
                <serverName>TextServerName</serverName>
            </RDPConnectionProperties>
        </value>
    </setting>
```

How would I read the different setting sections via their 'name'.

For example:
I if I would like to read the serverName in the "`<setting name="DefaultConnection>`" section.

So far, I've only been able to achieve the following:

```
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.Load("$home\user.config")
$xml.configuration.userSettings

name
----

FavoritesCollection
DefaultConnection
```

Comment: Answer = 

$xml.SelectSingleNode("configuration/userSettings/setting[@name='DefaultConnection']/value/RDPConnectionProperties/serverName")